# Beginner in C, array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to copy a string to a cell in array of strings.
I know it's a simple question, but I can't figure out why strcpy copies only the first char.

Please explain to a beginner :)

Something idiotic like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     10
#define MAX_INPUTS  3


void func(char array[MAX_INPUTS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH])
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
    strcpy(array[0], line);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char lines[MAX_INPUTS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    func(lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for me .. maybe you did print it wrong? Try `printf("%s\n", array[0]);` after `strcpy(array[0], line);`

Comment: Thanks! Feel so stupid no to print...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me (I made tiny adjustments) :

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 10
#define MAX_INPUTS 3

void func(char array[MAX_INPUTS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH]){
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
    strcpy(array[0], line);
}

/* no need to use main args in this case */
int main(void){
    char lines[MAX_INPUTS][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    func(lines);
    printf("str=%s\n", lines[0]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ gcc test.c -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out
something
str=something
```

Maybe it was your print which was wrong (wrong format, etc.) ?

Comment: Thanks. Stupid of me not to print it...
Follow up question:
In Eclipse, when viewing the lines array in the debug perspective, I can only see the first char of each line.
Why is that and how can view the entire line / cell of the array ?

Comment: @user2858571 Sorry, I haven't used eclipse for debugging C program. I suppose it is possible to add an expression by making `new/watch` or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Here: I modified the functions so that the memory is passed by reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH     10
#define MAX_INPUTS  3

void func(char **array)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
    strcpy(array[0], line);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char **lines = malloc(MAX_INPUTS); //allocate it on the stack so it can be changed easier
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_INPUTS; i++)
        lines[i] = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH * sizeof(*lines)); //allocate a multidimensional array
    func(lines);
    printf("%s\n", lines[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The array passed as a argument is already a pointer. Dynamic allocation is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: It works this way, whereas it did not work the original way. Stack memory is preferred in anything I do, its about preference and what works, and this works.

Comment: "whereas it did not work the original way" => it's wrong, see my answer (and dynamic allocation doesn't change anything in this case) ;)

Comment: I dont see the point in arguing, if your response works better than mine, then he/she should use yours. If yours works, great! So does mine. Please stop being a child.

Comment: Needless to take offense. When I'm wrong and when my answer is corrected by someone, I'm pretty happy (and it happens regularly).

Comment: "My output says it works fine." => Your code works but it doesn't mean that is a good practice to introduce dynamic allocation, or justify your arguments.

Comment: Please then, tell me why you dislike dynamic allocation?

Comment: I'm just saying that in your case, it's useless one hand because you made dynamic allocation ​on fixed sizes at the beginning of the program, on the other hand because you don't seem to be aware that the array are already pointers (no need to use this to pass as a reference).

Comment: Your code may work but it's not what the OP did or wanted, and it's unnecessary. Which means you changed something that was not related to the problem (which problem? ;-) ) which is distracting and useless.